# How to convert text to list of dict in Python

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, odoo-13

I have a text result like this:

```
{"title": "Less Payment", "outstanding": false, "content": [{"name": "Customer Payment: INV/2020/0002", "journal_name": "Cash", "amount": 50000.0, "currency": "Rp", "digits": [69, 2], "position": "before", "date": "2020-04-29", "payment_id": 13, "account_payment_id": 3, "payment_method_name": null, "move_id": 9, "ref": "CSH1/2020/0003 (INV/2020/0002)"}, {"name": "Customer Payment: INV/2020/0003", "journal_name": "Cash", "amount": 15000.0, "currency": "Rp", "digits": [69, 2], "position": "before", "date": "2020-04-29", "payment_id": 18, "account_payment_id": 4, "payment_method_name": null, "move_id": 11, "ref": "CSH1/2020/0004 (INV/2020/0003)"}]}
```

it seems dictionary, but actually the data type of that result is a string.

I want to convert that to the proper format so that I can process the data.

How to do that..?, or any tutorial or source to learn about that..?

For more information, I got the result from **Odoo13** **mail.template**, then I want to get the result from the **invoice_payments_widget** field from **account.move** object.

Comment: _it seems dictionary_ It seems? That is quite an important aspect. _actually the data type of that result is a string._ Then please provide a valid Python string. _For more information, I got the result from Odoo13 mail.template_ I was going to ask where it comes from, it's unfortunate that a library would return this kind of data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import json
my_json_string = "{'hi':5}"
res = json.loads(my_json_string)
print(res['hi']) # 5
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25983680)

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
x='{"title": "Less Payment", "outstanding": false, "content": [{"name": "Customer Payment: INV/2020/0002", "journal_name": "Cash", "amount": 50000.0, "currency": "Rp", "digits": [69, 2], "position": "before", "date": "2020-04-29", "payment_id": 13, "account_payment_id": 3, "payment_method_name": null, "move_id": 9, "ref": "CSH1/2020/0003 (INV/2020/0002)"}, {"name": "Customer Payment: INV/2020/0003", "journal_name": "Cash", "amount": 15000.0, "currency": "Rp", "digits": [69, 2], "position": "before", "date": "2020-04-29", "payment_id": 18, "account_payment_id": 4, "payment_method_name": null, "move_id": 11, "ref": "CSH1/2020/0004 (INV/2020/0003)"}]}'
x=json.loads(x)
```